# Representation of the expectation of absolute value of the difference $Y-X$

Tags: probability, expected-value, absolute-value

Given the representations of the mean values
$$E[Y]=\int(1-F(x))\,dx$$
and
$$E[X]=\int(1-G(x))\,dx$$ where $F$ and $G$ are the distributions of $Y$ and $X$ respectively,
can I use them to find the expression (or a bound) of $E[|Y-X|]?$ For instance,
is it true that
$$ E[|Y-X|]\leq\int |G(x)-F(x)|\,dx?$$

Comment: I'm slightly confused since the $Y$ and $X$ are two different random variables the integral shouldn't be $dxdy$?

Comment: Hint: consider the case where $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Or split it up into the two cases and use linearity and order preservation

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2920418/321264

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Not necessarily.  A simple example is that it is perfectly fine to write $E[X + Y] = \int_\mathbb{R} (2 - F(x) - G(x))dx$ for two different nonnegative r.v.s $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: NB: These expressions are correct only for non-negative random variables, so we should take that as an implicit assumption.  In that case, drawing a diagram of the three areas determined by those three integrals will be *extremely* suggestive ;-).

Comment: What do you assume about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$? Independence?

Comment: Are you assuming that the random variables are non-negative?

Answer (score 4):

As @whuber has pointed out, the expressions in your post are true for non-negative random variables, not in general.

For a random variable $X$ with distribution function $G$, one has in general

$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-G(x))\,\mathrm dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 G(x)\,\mathrm dx\,,$$

whenever the expectation exists.

As for your question, if $X,Y$ have distribution functions $G,F$ respectively, and $(X,Y)$ has distribution function $H$, then

$$E|Y-X|=\int (F(x)+G(x)-2H(x,x))\,\mathrm dx \,, \tag{$\star$}$$

whenever the expectation exists.

[An elegant proof of this result (no non-negativity assumption here) is shown in this Math.SE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2921866/1074816).]

In essence, this is based on the fact that

\begin{align}
|Y-X|&=(Y-X)\mathbf1_{\{Y\ge X\}}+(X-Y)\mathbf1_{\{Y< X\}}
\\&=\int \mathbf1_{\{X\le x\le Y\}}\,\mathrm dx + \int \mathbf1_{\{Y\le x\le X\}}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}

Taking expectation on both sides, and using Fubini/Tonelli's theorem yields $(\star)$.

In particular, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have

$$E|Y-X| = \int F(x)(1-G(x))\,\mathrm dx + \int G(x)(1-F(x))\,\mathrm dx $$

And when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d, this is just

$$E|Y-X|=2\int F(x)(1-F(x))\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: +1. I have added the direct link to the answer of the post you cited.